# Serialize and Deserialize from Vec<u32>

Tags: rust, serde

I have a struct of 5 `u32`s that implements serialize/deserialize by simply serializing: `(s.first, s.second, s.third, s.fourth, s.fifth)`.

However this needs to be packed and unpacked from a flat buffer of `Vec<u32>` or an `Option<Vec32>` that represent the data: essentially every 5 `u32`s is a new struct. I keep struggling with the visitor implementation. Is there an easy way to do this while sharing code between the `Option` and non `Option` cases?

I really want to do `impl Serialize for Vec<MyType>` (and `Deserialize`) but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up abandoning my `Serialize` and `Deserialize` impls and went with `#[serde(with="my_mod"]` for the `Vec<MyType`> case.

For the `Option<Vec<MyType>>` case I ended up creating wrapper types that inverted the relationship so that what I was really serializing/deserializing were `Option<Wrapper { Vec<T> }>`